# How does the lack of data about the Mesosphere affect our predictive knowledge of the atmosphere?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, data-analysis

Out of all the layers of the Earth's atmosphere the Mesosphere is the hardest to collect data and experiment on, due to it's density being too much for satellites and too little for aircraft or balloons.
Yet due to it's rarified air and it being a transient layer, I cannot think of how the lack of knowledge of this layer affects our understanding and predictive qualities of the Earth's system. That being the case, how would gathering more qualitative and quantitative data from the Mesosphere help?

Comment: I guess we might learn a lot about these strange lightnings occuring in the mesosphere: sprites, elves and the like. Also noctilucent clouds.

Comment: Those are phenomena we already know about, but is there any gap in our knowledge of them that affects other branches of Earth Science? Any mysteries that arise from them or anything else in the Mesosphere?

Comment: Actually we don't know much about those weird lightnings such as why they form, what effect they'd have on meteors and spacecraft passing through aso.